# I use windows 8.1 pro 32 bit, my query is regarding my laptop keyboard

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard

My laptop keyboard is misbehaving. It starts typing garbage and the down arrow key keeps scrolling my page down anytime. I wish to disable my internal keyboard as i have got myself a cheap USB keyboard. I went into the Device Manager and clicked on keyboard. I found two options which were,HID Keyboard Device and Standard PS/2 Keyboard. Now I am completely clueless about what to uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in your USB keyboard, then disable the "Standard PS/2 Keyboard". That's your laptop's built-in keyboard.

"HID" is a USB device class. It does not apply to the PS/2 keyboard. If you disable the HID device you will be unable to use your USB keyboard.

(Laptops use the old PS/2 interface for the built-in keyboard and mouse/trackpad/pointing stick/whatever because it's much less power-hungry than USB.)

Comment: thank u! tried that , but it is still not working.